# Open file editor from java

Tags: java, file, desktop, edit

I am trying to open file in external editor from java, but when i run my source code, nothing happens. I am using JRE 1.6 and my opration system is Windows 7. Here is my source code:

```
Desktop desktop = null;
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
  desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
}

 desktop.edit(new File("D:\\Document.rtf"));
```

Comment: Why don't you debug by putting some System.out.println() statements in the if block and also are there any exceptions thrown? This worked fine for me.

Comment: What happens when you try to open an rtf file on your machine without Java?

Comment: These 5 lines aren't enclosed inside `try {...} catch (Exception e) {}`? If they are, then you have your answer: don't ignore exceptions.

Comment: when i am trying to open that file in my machine, it is working correctly.

Comment: sorry for confusion, in my real source code i am catching exceptions. When i run my code, no exception is thrown and in the debugger i see, that command desktop = Desktop.getDesktop(); is really executed.

Comment: It's probably BECAUSE you're catching exceptions (and ignoring them) that you don't understand what happens. Don't ignor them, and you'll probably notice that an exception is thrown, with a message explaining why it was thrown.

Comment: I am having this same problem. I am catching all exceptions and printing the stack trace. No exceptions occur. The program just hangs. The worst part is that it worked a couple times for me and then just stopped. I ran my debugger in Eclipse and found that   
 checkAWTPermission();
        checkExec();
        checkActionSupport(Action.EDIT);
        file.canWrite();
        checkFileValidation(file);
all pass and do not throw any exceptions. I am using JDK 1.6.0_29 and windows 7.

Comment: I just restarted my computer and now it works. No code changes were made, I just restarted. really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should also work:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd /C D:\\Document.rtf" );
```

or

```
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String lcOSName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    boolean MAC_OS_X = lcOSName.startsWith("mac os x");
    if (MAC_OS_X) {
        run.exec("open " + file);
    } else {
        //run.exec("cmd.exe /c start " + file); //win NT, win2000
        run.exec("rundll32 url.dll, FileProtocolHandler " + path);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the OP should be given an alternate solution,rather be told what his mistakes are in the current code.

Comment: first solution is working nice for me. Thank you very much for that, you solved my problem. But i am still curious, why my original source code was not working ... hmm :)

Answer (score 0):

- did you read API

[public void edit(File file) throws IOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#edit%28java.io.File%29)

> Launches the associated editor application and opens a file for editing.
>
> Parameters:
>           file - the file to be opened for editing 
>      Throws:
>           NullPointerException - if the specified file is null 
>           IllegalArgumentException - if the specified file doesn't exist 
>           UnsupportedOperationException - if the current platform does not support the Desktop.Action.EDIT action 
>           IOException - if the specified file has no associated editor, or the associated application fails to be launched 
>           SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) method denies read access to the file, or SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String) method denies write access to the file, or it denies the AWTPermission("showWindowWithoutWarningBanner") permission, or the calling thread is not allowed to create a subprocess
>       See Also:
>           AWTPermission

- did you test for, and print StackTrace from

  a) [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

  b) [SecurityException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html)

Comment: hi, I tested both of these exception as you suggested, but none of them is thrown.